# Detox - get past WebView log in screen

Tags: react-native, detox

The app we've built uses the Salesforce SDK and their log in screens which use a webview. I understand that detox cannot interact with the webview.

Any suggestions to get around this? If I can log in by hand manually and start the tests from that point on that would work in my case. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not mock the SDK API to return a valid token, as if you have logged in? You can find more info on mocking in the Detox docs.

Comment: On Android, you may want to consider using UIAutomator (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator), available through this Detox API - https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicegetuidevice-android-only

Comment: @LeoNatan the sdk does the log in on the native side. If I could pass it the token that would be great but the SDK doesn't seem to expose that functionality to the JS side.